# the amount magnetic induction kVA?

Tags: autotransformer

the question and solution is given below:
[image]

### How did he know that 10 kVA is transformed by magnetic induction?

SOURCE: Electrical Machines, Drives, and Power Systems

by Theodore Wildi. Sixth edition, 2014.

ISBN 10: 1-292-02458-5

ISBN 13: 978-1-292-02458-5

Pearson Education Limited

Comment: Because he knows the secondary current and how it got there, as well as the secondary voltage.

Comment: For homework or study questions, the asker must show an attempt to solve. You should start by drawing a schematic diagram of the autotransformer connection.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a homework or study question with no demonstration of attempt to solve.